# How to store data in client PC from web browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I want to store data in client pc from web browser and through jquery code is it possible to store data in file system?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Its possible with using Web SQL but which is supported in Chrome, Safari and Opera Only but i want all browser compatibility so want to go for other option

Comment: Web SQL doesn't grant access to the file system.

Comment: You can with the [filesystem api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), but note it is not at all widely supported, i believe webkit(Google Chrome) is the only one that has limited support for it

Comment: Which kind of data do you want to store client side?

Comment: @A.Wolff I want to store large data like data for Charts

Comment: @A.Wolff, was meaning more specifically the requestFileSystem and associated functions. MDN says only supported by chrome, and tested in firefox and IE neither had access to it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans ya, after reading more carefully link you provided i then understood what you meant, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are  able to store some values in browsers local storage using cookies, it is stored in the client system...

You **cannot** use the **file system** of a client system to store data....

Answer (score 2):

Correct! Cookies are the only way.

Think just for one moment what is possibile to do if we can set/read anything we want on client machine......security before all!

Comment: No. use localstorage instead of cookies, especially for larger chunks of data

Comment: Hi Bergi, i never heard before. I read something now and u'r right it is more powerfull.